# Symmetry in functions

Tags: calculus

What's the difference between $f(x)=f(a-x)$ and $f(x)=f(x-a)$ ?

It's a pretty simple question maybe, but I'm unable to understand this one.

Comment: There is a possible confusion about names since you gave all functions involved the name $f$. Did you mean the difference between $g(x)=f(a-x)$ and $h(x)=f(x-a)$?

Comment: Just to illustrate, suppose that $a=0$.  then your first equation says $f(x)=f(-x)$ which tells us a lot about $f(x)$.  Your second equation just says $f(x)=f(x)$ which is unhelpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean two different things, and without knowing **what** it is that you don't understand, it's hard to know how to explain.

The way to understand it is to abandon algebra. Put $a=5$ and try different values of $x$: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on.

You will find that:

- $f(x)=f(a-x)$ means what it says. For example, that $f(0)=f(a)$ and $f(-1)=f(a+1)$. To summarize: $f$ is mirror-symmetrical about the value $x=\frac12{a}$.
- $f(x)=f(x-a)$ means what it says. For example, that $f(a)=f(0)=f(-a)$. To summarise: $f$ is periodic with period $a$.

**Note for pedants**: $f(x)=f(x-a)$ actually means that $f$ is periodic with period $|a|$ (that is, $a$ if $a$ is positive, $-a$ if $a$ is negative), and if $a=0$ if means $f(x)=f(x)$, which is always true but very uninteresting.

Comment: Oh thanks, got it...was doing irrational thinking 

Answer (score 1):

The sign "$-$" here refers to a binary operation, lets call it $O(x,y)=x-y$. Writing it like this shows the difference between $O(x,y)$ and $O(y,x)$

So the difference is $O(x,y)\neq O(y,x)$ since a binary operation does not have to be commutative, the result could be different.

There are a lot of examples of non commutative operation:

1. Composition of functions $f\circ g\neq g\circ f$.

2.Division $4/2\neq 2/4$.

3. Multiplication of matrices (with at least 2 rows).

To read more about non commutative binary operations I would suggest you read about basic Relations in Set Theory and about basic Group Theory.